# Pagination active link

Tags: php, ajax

I am doing pagination with ajax for table which has some 
 records for which i have to show active link for each 
 click.Please do help me with this.

```
      $(document).ready(function()
      {  
             ready_data();  
             function ready_data(page)  
       {  
         $.ajax({  
            url:"connection.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{page:page},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#paginate_record').html(data); 
                //  $('.page_links').removeClass('active');
                //  $(this).addClass('active');                  
            }  
       });   }  

     $(document).on('click', '.page_links ', function(){   
         var page = $(this).attr("id");  
         ready_data(page);  
     });  
    });
```

Here is My pagination page

```
    $records_per_page = 2;  
    $page = '';  

    if(isset($_POST["page"]))  
    {  
         $page = $_POST["page"];  
    }               
    else  
    {  
         $page = 1;  
    }  
    $start_from = ($page - 1)*$records_per_page; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students  LIMIT $start_from, 
    $records_per_page"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $data .= '</table><br /><div align="center">';  
    $page_sql = "SELECT * FROM students ";  
    $page_result = mysqli_query($con, $page_sql);  
    $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($page_result);  
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records/$records_per_page);

    for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)  
    {    

      $data.= "<span class='page_links active' 
      style='cursor:pointer;margin:10px;padding:1px;border:1px 
       solid 
      ;'id='".$i."'>".$i."</span>";  

    }

    echo $data;
```

Now in which i want to show active link for each click.i tried by adding class on ajax succes function also add the active class on span tag but it is applying to all links.so please do help me.

Answer (score 1):

In the last `for()` loop, you are applying the `active` class to all the output, you want to apply this only to the current page...

```
   for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)  
    {    

      $data.= "<span class='page_links";
      if ( $i == $page ) {
          $data .=" active";
      }
      $data.= "' style='cursor:pointer;margin:10px;padding:1px;border:1px solid;'id='"
               .$i."'>".$i."</span>";  

    }
```